# List of a Generic Typed Parent not Accepting a Child with a Type that is a Subtype of the Parent List's Type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, geometry-class-library

Here is my current class diagram:

[image]

As you can see, both `Polygon` and `NonPolygon` are types of `PlaneRegion` and `LineSegment` implements `IEdge`.The `PlaneRegion` is Generic so we can make its list of `PlaneBoundaries` either `IEdge` for `NonPolygon` so it can have `LineSegment` or `arc`, or so that they can be only `LineSegment` for `Polygon`. Below is samples of the classes to show how it is implemented:

```
public class PlaneRegion<T> : Plane, where T : IEdge
{
    public virtual List<T> PlaneBoundaries { get; set; }
}

public class Polygon : PlaneRegion<LineSegment>
{
    #region Fields and Properties
    public override List<LineSegment> PlaneBoundaries
    {
        get { return _planeBoundaries; }
        set { _planeBoundaries = value; }
    }
    protected List<LineSegment> _planeBoundaries;
}

public class NonPolygon : PlaneRegion<IEdge>
{
    public override List<IEdge> PlaneBoundaries
    {
        get { return _planeBoundaries; }
        set { _planeBoundaries = value; }
    }
    private List<IEdge> _planeBoundaries;
}
```

This all works fine, but when I try to make a list of `PlaneRegion<IEdge>` it will not let me add a `Polygon` object to the list despite `Polygon` being a `PlaneRegion<LineSegment>` and `LineSegment` implemting `IEdge`. This is an example of the code that gives me a compile time error:

```
List<PlaneRegion<IEdge>> planes = new List<PlaneRegion<IEdge>>();

Polygon polygon1 = new Polygon();      
NonPolygon nonPolygon1 = new NonPolygon();

planes.Add(polygon1); //says that .Add() has some invalid arguments
planes.Add(nonPolygon1);
```

Is there a way to add `polygon1` to this list that is type safe? I tried casting `polygon1` to type `PlaneRegion<IEdge>` but that gave a compile error that it cannot convert the types. I know I can do `(PlaneRegion<IEdge>)(object)` but it seems sloppy and unsafe so it seems there should be a better way.

Comment: Given types `U` and `V` and generic type `G<T>`, `U:V` does not imply that `G<U>:G<V>` - that is, inheritance relationships between types do not imply inheritance relationships between generics derived from those types. So a `PlaneRegion<LineSegment>` is *not* a `PlaneRegion<IEdge>`.

Comment: Casting won't help, by the way - that will fail at execution time. Simply put, a `PlaneRegion<LineSegment>` is *not* a `PlaneRegion<IEdge>`. Consider what `region.PlaneBoundaries.Add(new Arc())` does, if `region` is decalred as `PlaneRegion<IEdge>` but is a `PlaneRegion<LineSegment>` at execution time...

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I see what the problem is, but is there no way to do something like this or do it another way that achieves a similar result that avoids the problem?

Comment: Have you tried creating an `IPlaneRegion<T>` interface and making it covariant? Then you can use that as the compile-time type. I may be wrong but as far as I can see your current classes satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works fine for me:

```
public class Polygon : PlaneRegion<IEdge> 
{
    public new List<LineSegment> PlaneBoundaries
    {
        get { return (_planeBoundaries); }
        set { _planeBoundaries = value; }
    }
    protected List<LineSegment> _planeBoundaries;
}
```